# How to aggregate non numerical values on power bi?

Tags: powerbi

I have a matrix with numerical values assigned to securities ratings.

Let's say B- = 16 and B+ = 14, with both weighing 50% of the portfolio. In that case, the overall portfolio score would be 15 ((14 + 16)/2), which is assigned to a B rating.

How can I 'convert' back that 15 weighted average to a letter on the grand total?

[image]